# Duration of day and night on Pandora

Tags: avatar

In ***Avatar***, as **Pandora** itself is a moon orbiting around a planet, that in turn orbits around a star, does it (**Pandora**) have random number of hours in day and night? Is there any reference about it?

Comment: You're asking if there is an annual variation (like on Earth) or if there's a  variation that's really random? If the former [this article](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Pandora#Day-Night_Cycle) confirms it (as well as providing more info about the day-night cycle).

Comment: I meant really random. Today it may be of 5 hours tomorrow may be 23 hours.. like that..

Comment: The article (already posted as an answer) mentions only annual variation, so it seems that no randomness is considered.

Comment: Inherently it can't be random, in fact it's day/night-cycle would be incredibly precise and predictable, just not as metronomic as Earths.

Answer (score 5):

[From this site](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Pandora)

> Pandora receives significant light from Alpha Centauri B (ACB). As a
>   result, Pandoran nights are never dark during half of the Polyphemian
>   year, but instead are more like Earthly dusk. At the closest point in
>   its orbit, ACB is about 2,300 times as bright as Earth's full moon; at
>   its furthest point, it is still one hundred and seventy times as
>   bright. During the other half of the year when ACB is in the daytime
>   sky, many Pandoran nights are illuminated by both Polyphemus's huge
>   disk and the reflected light from other nearby moons. Truly dark
>   nights are uncommon. Polyphemus occasionally eclipses ACB at night for
>   about one hundred minutes, but the light reflected by the planet still
>   keeps the night from being dark.
>
> When ACB shares the daytime sky with ACA, at its closest it adds about
>   half a percent to the total illumination. When the 2 stars are close
>   together in the sky, the effect of ACB's more orange light is
>   unnoticeable. But, as they separate over the years, an orange tint may
>   be seen in areas shadowed from ACA's direct illumination. At its most
>   distant, ACB is about 2,700 times dimmer than ACA and does not produce
>   noticeable lighting effects. However, it still appears as a
>   blindingly-bright tiny orange disk in the sky.
>
> Because of its high axial tilt (29°), Pandora exhibits considerable
>   annual variation in the day-to-night ratio. In addition, its
>   elliptical orbit produces seasonal temperature variations and a range
>   in daytime illumination of about ten percent.

Comment: So are there any color changes in the environment?

Comment: I couldn't find anything, but I guess that the color changes, since the light of the stars are different. The light that comes from the planet is also different.